# Quicksort algorithm time complexity for a particular kind of array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

I'm taking an algorithms course, and would like some help with the following question:

> What is the time complexity of the quicksort algorithm on the array `[k+1, ..., n, 1, ..., k]` where `k > n/2`, and the pivot is always chosen to be the right-most cell of the sub-array?
>
> Will it be `O(n²)` or `O(n log n)`?

From a scanned algorithms test from a past semester, the student said `O(n²)` (which I agreed with after a few simulations), but that student got the answer wrong with no explanations.
Me and a couple of other students are confused as to why the answer is marked wrong when all three of us got to the same conclusion by ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

O(n²) is correct.

The first run through will select the right-most element `k` as the pivot, partitioning the rest of the array into `[1, ..., k-1]` on the left and `[k+1, ..., n]` on the right. Since both of these subarrays are in sorted order, they are in a form where quicksort selecting the right-most element as the pivot takes quadratic time.

Sorting the left side of the partition will therefore take O(k²) time, and sorting the right side will take O((n-k)²) time. Since we have `n/2 < k <= n`, we also have that O(k²) = O(n²).